# Where is the WinUSB application template?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio

I am trying to follow [these directions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn376872(v=vs.85).aspx), this is my first USB device driver using windows. Unfortunately, I do not see the winUSB project file, and I also do not know how to get it. 
I am using Visual-Studio 2015 Community Edition.
[image]

Comment: I am not convinced that article applies to Visual Studio 2015.  It specifically mentions previous versions.  Do you have the appropriate WDK packages installed though?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the MSDN page you link to:

> For this template, you need an integrated environment with the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) (with Debugging Tools for Windows) and Microsoft Visual Studio (Professional or Ultimate)

From [Microsoft Hardware Dev Center - Download the WDK, WinDbg, and associated tools](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit):

> All three editions of Visual Studio 2015 support driver development.

The page then continues to list four editions, including the Community edition.

Below that, it shows:

> Download the [Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=526733).